# MVC Model Binder doesn't recognize JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I'm passing a JSON object from an AJAX call to an MVC Controller Action with an object that should match the JSON as the passed parameter. But all properties of the object are null, the model binder doesn't seem to be doing it's job, though I can't find any discrepancy. The ViewModel in the controller parameter is as follows...

```
public ActionResult ExportPatientDetailsToExcel(CaseReviewExcelTable tbl)
{
}


 public class CaseReviewExcelTable
    {
        public Guid CaseID { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Label;
        public string Value;
    }
```

...and according to Fiddler the JSON object being passed has this structure...

```
-JSON
    -CaseReviewExcelTable
        -CaseID = '<correct GUID value here>'
        -Header = '<header string here>'
        -Rows 
            -{}
                -Row
                    -Items
                         -{}
                             -Item
                                 -Label = '<label string Here>'
                                 -Value = '<value string here>'
                         -{}
            -{}
            -{}
```

Here's the gist of the AJAX call...

```
function exportPatientDetailsToExcel(caseId)
{
    var caseReviewExcelTable = createTableObj();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/CasesToReview/ExportPatientDetailsToExcel',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ CaseReviewExcelTable: caseReviewExcelTable }),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('got details')
        },
        dataType: 'HTML'
    });
}

function createTableObj()
{
    var header = $('#tblPatientDetails tr').first().find('b').text()
    var caseId = $('#tblPatientDetails tr').first().find('input[type="hidden"]#caseId').val()
    var rows = new Array();
    $('#tblPatientDetails tr').not(':first').each(function () {
        var items = new Array();
        $(this).children('td.detailsNameLbl').each(function () {
            var lbl = $(this).text();
            var val = $(this).next().text();
            var item = { Label: lbl, Value: val };
            items.push({ Item: item });
        });
        var row = { Items: items };
        rows.push({ Row: row });
    });
    var caseReviewExcelTable = { CaseID: caseId, Header: header, Rows: rows };
    return caseReviewExcelTable;
}
```

- EDIT JasonP's comment worked, below is what I changed and now everything's populating except Item.label and Item.Value, which are still null and which I'm stuck on now. Below are the 2 other lines I had to

  ```
   var header = $('#tblPatientDetails tr').first().find('b').text()
      var caseId = $('#tblPatientDetails tr').first().find('input[type="hidden"]#caseId').val()
      var rows = new Array();
      $('#tblPatientDetails tr').not(':first').each(function () {
          var items = new Array();
          $(this).children('td.detailsNameLbl').each(function () {
              var lbl = $(this).text();
              var val = $(this).next().text();
              var item = { Label: lbl, Value: val };
              ***items.push(item);***
          });
          var row = { Items: items };
          ***rows.push(row);***
      });
      var caseReviewExcelTable = { CaseID: caseId, Header: header, Rows: rows };
      return caseReviewExcelTable;
  }
  ```

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify(caseReviewExcelTable)`

Comment: Why you using two dataType's `json` and `html` ???

Comment: @webdeveloper - oops you're right, good catch. Removing dataType: 'json' didn't fix it though

Comment: You should remove `html` )))

Comment: @webdeveloper - no I'm expecting HTML back, but that's not even an issue right now, the correct binding is not occurring when the controller action is called

Comment: @JasonP - Awesome, your answer plus a few other things in the same vein worked, now everything's populated except Item.Label and Item.Value. See my edit

Comment: Where is `[HttpPost]` near `ExportPatientDetailsToExcel` ?

Comment: Try `items.push(item);` without `Item`

Comment: found the problem, i had Item properties as fields, not properties. Had to add { get; set; }